# Adding new item to recommender's options?

Tags: recommender-system

My shop has 20-items with a recommender system on top which analyses history of purchases and recommends items to buy each time customer returns.

Now I want to add an additional item to choose from, which I have no history about previous purchases (let's say customers purchased it from my competitor). In a while, I will  add this new item to recommender engine, but I'm afraid it will think that the item is less popular than 20-items with good history.

I guess I need to add some kind of adjustment to recommender engine, and (as 
I'm newbie to recommender system)  what kind of adjustments should I look at/google for?
Should I look at `cold-start` problem, like was proposed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/63186/31266)?

Comment: cold-start is precisely the problem you have

Comment: Yes `cold-start` is the correct term. It also applies to new customers for whom you have no past activity.

Comment: if your recommender system explicitly constructs user feature vectors and product feature vectors, then creating a product feature vector for the new product is a possible path forward.